# Install Shield LE erros -1014 and -5044

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, add-in, installshield-2012

I created an install project for my addin and keep getting these two errors:[image]

I have searched all over for how to solve them and haven't been able to find much on them. Does anyone have any information on them that would lead me in the right direction?

Comment: I often use Process Explorer to find what's holding a file or directory open. Then I can kill the relevant process and/or restart the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. If you are currently in Windows Explorer and are in the same directory looking at the install files, it will throw this error. Back out of the directory and it wont throw an error.